# WCF: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]

Tags: .net, wcf, https, iis-7, basichttpbinding

I hava wcf service built with framework 4. and hosted to IIS using https.

below is my configuration file and error i got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WebService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebService.IService1" bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="h" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WebService.IService1" bindingConfiguration="" behaviorConfiguration="" />

        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="WebService.IService1"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="20000000" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="20000000" maxStringContentLength="20000000" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Error Returned

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Comment: Don't you need to configure your WebHttpBinding to use transport security? I don't see it in your bindings element for webHttpBinding.

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here...

Based on your configuration file and the error message you're receiving, it appears you need to set the `security` mode of your `webHttpBinding` to `Transport`.

You can see from the documentation, by default the `security` property on a [WebHttpBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.webhttpsecurity.mode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ServiceModel_WebHttpSecurity_Mode) is None.

To use the HTTPS protocol, you would need to set the `security` mode to `Transport`

The configuration for your WebHttpBinding would be as follows:

```
<webHttpBinding>
     <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000">
         <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="20000000" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="20000000" maxStringContentLength="20000000" />
         <security mode="Transport">
     </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```